# How to keep clean geometry, when beveling boolean cutouts

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry, bevel

I want to model this gun:
[image]

So I started to cut out the rough shapes from a cube (using the boolean modifier)
Then I tried to clean up the geometry to be able to round the edges of the handguard.
[image]

But it does not work. When I try to bevel it like in the last pic top right it just gets really messy.
[image]

I think I took the wrong approach. How would you go about adding clean and workable geometry to such a piece and would you use the Bevel tool to create the round shapes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The artifacts are caused by beveling too tight geometry.
It good to keep some space near edges specifically for beveling.

[image]