# Bevel modifier not working on certain sharpened edges. (Hard-ops/Box cutter) 2.93

Tags: edges, bevel

[image]

I've tried merging verts that were too close to each other and using a weld modifier but it didn't solve my issue. It works when I bevel ctrl+b instead of using the modifier.I have tried reseting scale. The edges attached to the cylinder shape just wont bevel with the modifier. This is all one merged object originally 2 seperate objects before I merged them for the bevel.

Comment: Related: [How to keep clean geometry, when beveling boolean cutouts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214017/78972)

Comment: please provide blend file