# How can I bevel weapon's handle?

Tags: bevel

I am working on M4 model, and I have finished the base mesh (image 1).

When I mark edges and use bevel - weird thing is going on, totally unexpected (image 2).

Rotation & scale is 1-1-1.

**IMAGE 1**

[image]

**IMAGE 2**

[image]

Comment: Hello :). The geometry is too tight. Related: [How to bevel boolean cutouts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214017/78972)

Comment: Well, it isn't a boolean cut actually, but I will check it

Comment: I recommend using Limited Dissolve on the model first.