# Issues with bevel modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I have some issues with bevel modifier. It works improperly if clamp overlap is enabled (real bevel amount is small and cannot be changed). When it's disabled it causes such artefacts. I know that my topology might not be very good because of the ngons, but the only way to get rid of them that I know is manual, and I'm not sure if it is the best way.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: issues with bevel modifier]
[image: overall topology]

Comment: Hello :). Related: [How to keep clean geometry, when beveling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214017/78972)

Comment: @Jachym Michal, hello! Those shading problems came after bevel modifier, which was applied to the edges marked blue. I still don't understand what exactly causes this problem.

Comment: Hey :). The point is, you want some undisturbed space around the edges - that way the bevel will be nice and even. Yes, you'll need to do that manually in this case :).